# Connect failed RosAria with Robot

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed RosAria, and using the command

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and

```
rosrun rosaria RosAria
```

output:

```
[ INFO] [1479721570.365432614]: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
Connnecting to robot using TCP connection to localhost:8101...
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
Syncing 0 No packet.
Syncing 0 No packet.
Trying close possible old connection
Syncing 0 No packet.
Syncing 0 No packet.
Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0 No packet.
Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0 No packet.
Could not connect, no robot responding.
Failed to connect to robot.
[ERROR] [1479721576.820760721]: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot! (Check ~port parameter is correct, and permissions on port device.)
[FATAL] [1479721576.820794938]: RosAria: ROS node setup failed...
```

Pleasem help me to fix this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248531/connect-failed-rosaria-with-robot/) by [ThiemPHAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28524/thiempham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-21**:
I've cleaned your post up a bit. Should be more readable like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the error. There is not synchronization between baud rate of RS232 of Robot and that of my computer.

---

Originally posted by [ThiemPHAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28524/thiempham/) with karma: 46 on 2016-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2021-06-29**:
I am having the same problem, could you elaborate on what you mean? Here's my post on the question: https://answers.ros.org/question/381440/seekur-jr-cant-connect-or-sync/